# No funciona URL en php (include)

Tags: php

Estoy intentando de insertar un archivo con un `include`, pero por alguna razón no funciona con la URL completa.

Esto funciona:

```
<?php include 'menu.html' ?>
```

Pero esto no es así:

```
<?php include 'http://domainname.com/menu.html' ?>
```

¿Alguna idea?

PD: Tengo entendido el peligro de seguridad de hacer esto.

Comment: Básicamente es que `include` busca a nivel de sistema de ficheros, de disco, no por URL... es decir, la ruta completa sería algo como `/var/www/html/myapp/menu.html`

Comment: Es un ejemplo, por que si deseara buscar en una url externa a mi localhost, necesitaría el "http://" es por ello que pregunto

Comment: Para obtener un fichero externo por php debes habilitar y utilizar curl, con un simple include o require no podrás como ya bien te indicaron sólo accedes a archivos en el disco local y en directorios donde tengas permisos

Comment: Tal vez esta función te valga. http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Debido a las respuesta que te dan, que tu sepas la falla de seguridad que implica hacer esto, te recomiendo crear el archivo que quieres incluir en tu sitio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para poder incluir archivos remotamente, debes establecer las directivas [`allow_url_include, allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/es/filesystem.configuration.php) en `on` en el archivo `php.ini`.

Desde el punto de vista de seguridad, es malo hacerlo, por eso generalmente está deshabilitado.

E intenta incluirlo así:

```
<?php 
    include 'http://domainname.com/menu.html'; 
?>
```

Aqui puedes ver algunas razones por lo que no es recomendable:
https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214205688-allow-url-include

Answer (score 1):

Es posible incluir archivos remotos en PHP, tal y como dice la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php):

> Si las "[envolturas URL include](http://php.net/manual/es/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include)" están activadas en PHP, se puede
>   especificar el archivo a ser incluido usando una URL (vía HTTP u otra
>   envoltura soportada - ver [Protocolos y Envolturas soportados](http://php.net/manual/es/wrappers.php) para
>   una lista de protocolos) en lugar de una ruta de acceso local. Si el
>   servidor objetivo interpreta el archivo objetivo como código PHP, las
>   variables se pueden pasar al archivo incluido usando una string de
>   petición como la usada con HTTP GET. Esto no es, en estricto rigor, lo
>   mismo que haber incluido el archivo y que haya heredado el ámbito de
>   variables del archivo padre; el script realmente está siendo ejecutado
>   en el servidor remoto y el resultado entonces se incluye dentro del
>   script local.

Para detalles más específicos sobre la inclusión de archivos HTML puedes ver [la información del Manual de PHP al respecto](http://php.net/manual/es/wrappers.http.php).

De todos modos:

**A.**

Si tu archivo está en el mismo servidor, la forma de incluirlo es haciendo referencia a la ruta en que se encuentra dicho archivo, como dice el Manual:

> Los archivos **son incluidos con base en la ruta de acceso dada** o, si
>   ninguna es dada, el `include_path` especificado. Si el archivo no se
>   encuentra en el `include_path`, include finalmente verificará en el
>   propio directorio del script que hace el llamado y en el directorio de
>   trabajo actual, antes de fallar. El constructor include emitirá una
>   advertencia si no puede encontrar un archivo, éste es un
>   comportamiento diferente al de require, el cual emitirá un error
>   fatal..

La ruta de acceso en este caso hace referencia a la ruta en el servidor, no a una ruta URL.

**B.**

Si tu archivo está en otro servidor, no te recomendaría **nunca** incluir archivos de otro servidor, tendrías para ello que modificar la configuración de `php.ini` permitiendo un acceso **peligroso**, lo cual sería más costoso y inseguro que copiar dicho archivo en el propio servidor e incluirlo por la vía normal indicada en **A**.

Answer (score 1):

esto deberia funcionar

```
$handler = curl_init("http://domainname.com/menu.html");  
$response = curl_exec ($handler);  
curl_close($handler);  
echo $response
```

ponlo en donde va el menu

saludos

nota: investiga mas sobre curl para mas opcion

Answer (score 0):

El include no funciona para ficheros remotos. Solo incluye del mismo sistema de archivos.

Comment: esto es un comentario, no una respuesta.

Comment: No es un comentario, es una respuesta. El include de por si, no incluye ficheros remotos de PHP.

Comment: @AritzEzkiaga, es configurable. No recomendado pero si se puede. Tal como lo indica la otra respuesta.

Comment: Si, pero es practicamente imposible hacerlo, ya que nadie permitiria incluir ficheros que no esten en tu sistema de archivos.

Comment: El asume la falla de seguridad que implica hacer lo que quiere. Claramente la solución es crear el archivo en el sistema de archivo apropiado.

Comment: En la respuesta anterior, se incluye un link sobre cómo se hace, y porqué no debería hacerse.

Comment: ¿Quién es el que solo incluye del mismo sistema? Solo estás mencionando el problema, no parece una respuesta.

Comment: La funcion include del PHP.