# Insertar URL por CURL me arroja un carácter no esperado

Tags: php, curl

Vi en la siguiente consulta cómo incluir una página por URL dentro de otra PHP:

[No funciona URL en php (include)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76629/no-funciona-url-en-php-include)

El código entregado en una de las respuestas, utilizando CURL, me funcionó y me viene muy bien. Pero me arroja un problema. Se trata de un script que rota banners (el que se inserta), y bajo los banners donde he puesto la solución mediante CURL, me aparece un número "1" ¿Alguien sabe cómo eliminarlo, o por qué aparece?

El código utilizado:

```
$handler = curl_init("http://dominio.com/banners.php");
$response = curl_exec ($handler);
curl_close($handler);
echo $response
```

[image: esa es una muestra]

Saludos, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola, elimina la línea `echo $response`. Recuerda que `curl_exec()` devuelve un booleano. `$response` puede ser *true* (1) o *false* (0).